# Commenting requires wordpress login, wordpress discussion and post comments tick boxes are checked

Tags: php, themes, comments

The theme developer / customizer is not helping and I am an amateur in coding. For commenting on the page I need to be logged in as a wordpress user. Below code is from comment.php . Earlier i have had people who were able to comment but something changed sometime back. Theme here is Portada elegant blogging theme. Is there a way to make commenting normal or remove the requirement from the code to be compulsorily registered as  a user to comment. I can use native wordpress tickboxes to enforce that if required.

```php
<?php
if((comments_open()) && (!post_password_required()))
{
    $Comment=new Portada_ThemeComment();
    ?>
    <div id="comments" class="theme-clear-fix" data-cpage="<?php echo (int)$Comment->page; ?>">
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    </div>
<?php
    $commenter=wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req=get_option('require_name_email');
    $aria_req=($req ? ' aria-required=\'true\'' : '');

    $field=array();

    $field['author']=
        '
                <p class="theme-comment-form-field-33">
                    <label for="author" class="theme-infield-label">'.esc_html__('Name','portada').($req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '').'</label>
                    <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']).'" size="30"'.$aria_req.'/>
                </p>
            ';

    $field['email']=
        '
                <p class="theme-comment-form-field-33">
                    <label for="email" class="theme-infield-label">'.esc_html__('Email','portada').($req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '').'</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']).'" size="30"'.$aria_req.'/>
                </p>
            ';

    $field['url']=
        '
                <p class="theme-comment-form-field-33">
                    <label for="url" class="theme-infield-label">'.esc_html__('Website','portada').'</label>
                    <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_url']).'" size="30"/>
                </p>
            ';

    $commentField=
        '
                <p class="theme-clear-fix theme-comment-form-field-100">
                    <label for="comment" class="theme-infield-label">'.esc_html__('Comment','portada').' <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                </p>    
            ';

    $argument=array
    (
        'id_form'               =>  'comment-form',
        'title_reply'           =>  __('Leave a Reply','portada'),
        'cancel_reply_link'     =>  __('Cancel Reply','portada'),
        'comment_field'         =>  $commentField,
        'fields'                =>  apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields',$field),
        'label_submit'          =>  __('Leave a Reply','portada')
    );

    comment_form($argument);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kanishka

You can try disabling that by going to Setting>>Discussion:Other comment settings and uncheck the option `Users must be registered and logged in to comment`.